# JTable cell editor doesn't work when set using setCellEditor method

Tags: java, swing, jtable

There's a problem I'm having with getting the cell editor to work with my JTable.

I instantiated the JTable in the usual way (the JTable contains empty rows and columns):

```
table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(4,4));
```

and then wanted to see if a cell editor can work with it using the [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableDialogEditDemoProject/src/components/ColorEditor.java) from Oracle tutorials.

Surprisingly it works only if I set it for every column separately (first line below), but I'm unable to set it for the whole table (second line).

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new ColorEditor());       
table.setCellEditor(new ColorEditor());
```

Any ideas why this might be the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [`TableDialogEditDemo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableDialogEditDemoProject/src/components/TableDialogEditDemo.java) uses [`setDefaultEditor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setDefaultEditor-java.lang.Class-javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor-), which will evoke the `ColorEditor` for all cells whose type is `Color.class`.

```
table.setDefaultEditor(Color.class, new ColorEditor());
```

The table will invoke `setCellEditor()` for you when you edit a cell.

Comment: Oh my... I didn't notice the setDefaultEditor even exists. Thanks. I used the wrong method.